# How to read Maven repository credentials only when needed?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, maven-publish

I have a Gradle Kotlin DSL script that publishes some artifacts to a local Maven repository:

```
    publishing {
        publications {
            create<MavenPublication>("maven") {
                groupId = "my.company"
                artifactId = project.name
                version = "0.0.1"
                from(components["java"])
            }
        }
        repositories {
            maven {
                url = uri("https://maven.mycompany.com/content/repositories/whatever")
                credentials {
                    username = (read from some file)
                    password = (read from some file)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see, Gradle will *always* try to read the username and password from file. Even if the publish task isn't going to be executed.

I tried to fix it by moving the credentials to a `doFirst` block in the publish task, but the code is simply never executed:

```
publishing {
  doFirst { // this doesn't compile, doFirst doesn't exist here 
  }
}
tasks.getByName("publish").doFirst {
  // this compiles just fine, but it's never executed
}
tasks.named("publish") {
  doFirst {
    // this compiles just fine, but it's never executed
  }
}
```

How do I set credentials so that it only happens when executing the publish task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are always configuring the credentials regardless if they are needed or not. You need to conditionally configure the credentials. This can be accomplished in many ways.

For example, let's say you never want to publish snapshot versions. Your build could look something like:

```
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"

publishing {
    publications {
        create<MavenPublication>("maven") {
            from(components["java"])
        }
        repositories {
            maven {
                url = uri("https://maven.mycompany.com/content/repositories/whatever")
                if (!version.toString().contains("SNAPSHOT")) {
                    credentials {
                        username = property("username") as String
                        password = property("password") as String
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Notice the conditional. During the [configuration](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html#sec:build_phases) phase, Gradle will evaluate that condition and skip `credentials { }` because the version contains `SNAPSHOT`.

As I said, there are a variety of ways you can do the above. However, the best way is to use environment variables:

```
publishing {
    publications {
        create<MavenPublication>("maven") {
            from(components["java"])
        }
        repositories {
            maven {
                url = uri("https://maven.mycompany.com/content/repositories/whatever")
                credentials {
                    username = System.getenv()["username"]
                    password = System.getenv()["password"]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

No conditions whatsoever. `null` is an acceptable value for the credentials and doesn't matter during the configuration phase. It only matters when you publish is when you will get a `NullPointerException`

Comment: I went with a combination of your two suggestions: A conditional using an environment variable to toggle reading the credentials, and reading the credentials itself as project variables (from a gradle.properties file in my encrypted home folder).